# Node redis ETIMEOUT issue

Tags: node.js, azure, redis, node-redis

I've been using node-redis for a while and so far so good. However, upon setting up a new environment, I had a typo on the hostname (or password) and it wouldn't connect. But because this was an already working application I developed some time ago, it was kind of hard to track the actual issue. When you made requests against this server, it would just take up to the server's timeout which was 5 minutes and come back with error 500.

At the end I found out that it was the credentials for the redis server. I use redis to make my app faster by preventing revalidating security tokens for up to an hour (since the validation process can take up to 2000ms), so I store the token on redis for future requests.

This has worked fine for years, however, just because this time I had a typo on the hostname or password, I noticed that if the redis server can't connect (for whaterver reason) the whole application goes down. The idea is that redis should be used if available, if not it should fallback to just take the long route but fulfill the request anyway.

So my question is, how to tell node-redis to throw an error as soon as possible, and not wait until ETIMEOUT error comes?

For example:

```
const client = redis.createClient(6380, "redis.host.com", { password: "verystrongone" } });
client.on("error", err => {
    console.log(err)
})
```

Based on this code, I get the console.log error AFTER it reaches timeout (around 30-40 seconds). This is not good, because then my application is AT LEAST 30 seconds unresponsive. What I want to achieve is that if the redis is down or something, it should just give up after 2-5 seconds. I use a very fast and reliable redis server from Azure. It takes less than a second to connect, and has never failed, I believe, but if it does, it will take the whole application with it.

I tried stuff like `retry_strategy` but I believe that option kicks in only after the initial ~30 seconds attempt.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

So here's an interesting thing I observed.

When I connect to the redis cache instance using the following options, I am able to reproduce the error you're getting.

```
    port: 6380,
    host: myaccount.redis.cache.windows.net,
    auth_pass: mysupersecretaccountkey
```

When I specify incorrect password, I get an error after 1 minute.

However, if I specify `tls` parameter I get an error almost instantaneously:

```
    port: 6380,
    host: myaccount.redis.cache.windows.net,
    auth_pass: mysupersecretaccountkey,
    tls: {
      servername: myaccount.redis.cache.windows.net
    }
```

Can you try with `tls` option?

I am still not able to reproduce the error if I specify incorrect account name. I get the following error almost instantaneously:

> Redis connection to
>   myincorrectaccountname.redis.cache.windows.net:6380 failed -
>   getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND myincorrectaccountname.redis.cache.windows.net